# Anylogic DES- Split a queue to go to two delays (processes)?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

i'm modelling a production line with a diverging part line that uses the same part in two different assemblies. I can't figure out how the split the final queue/buffer to go to whichever assembly point is open/idle?

```
      ->assembly machene 1
```

Queue

```
      ->assembly machene 2
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the [guide on how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Especially explain in detail what your probelm is, what you already tried (!) and what the desired outcome is. Include code and images if neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [*Select Output*](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/_ProcessModeling/SelectOutput.html?cp=2_0_1_4) block from the *Process Modeling Library* to implement a decision point.

In the properties of that block, use the *If condition is true* setting and a condition that takes into account the status of your two machines (eg. `machine1.`).

Depending on your requirements you might need additional queues in front of your machines or a *Hold* block to not allow any flow while all machines are busy. However, the exact implementation depends on your exact requirements and can't be laid out in general.

I reccomend working through the AnyLogic tutorials, example models and the book [AnyLogic in three days](https://www.anylogic.com/resources/books/free-simulation-book-and-modeling-tutorials/) to get the basics of process modeling in AnyLogic.

Comment: Any recommendation to see if a `delay` currently has an agent in it? In the UI there is a `Contains` int, but I cannot access it through Java code?